# iOS Dev, How can I call a method in the super class of my UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i have two UIViewControllers for example A and B.

On A there is a button when pushed loads view B as a sub view. Using the standard initWithNibName. On B there is a button which dismisses View B and should call a method in view A (its Parent View). I thought it should be a simple [super methoddName:perimeter] but this doesn't work. after placing a NSLog printing out the name of the parentViewController it returned null which is odd as surly it should return View A as the Parent view.

any Ideas Cheers

Answer (score 0):

super refers to your class's superclass, not its parent view controller.

A way to quickly do this is create a new init method that takes an instance of view controller A, use that to set the target of your button.

The best way is to define a new protocol on view controller B. Make view controller A conform to it. On init of B, pass in a refernce to A to use as your delegate. Then on the button push in B call the desired method on the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off by letting view controller `A` be a delegate on view controller `B`.

`A` can set the delegate property on `B` when after loading it but before pushing it into view, and when B needs to call the required method, it can just call it on the delegate object.

That makes the coupling between the controllers looser, and if you let the delegate conform to a protocol, you can keep `B`'s knowledge of `A` to a minimum.

It's better design, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

`parentViewController` won't work if you add view controller B's view as a subview. You will have to find the view controller A in a different way.

Say, if you had added B's view as a subview like this,

```
[A.view addSubview:B.view];
```

then you can call view controller A like this.

```
[[B.view.superview nextResponder] methoddName:perimeter];
```

If you have added `B.view` as a subview somewhere within the view hierarchy of `A.view`.

```
UIResponder * responder = B.view.superview;
do {
    responder = [responder nextResponder];
} while ( ![responder isMemberOfClass:[A class]] );

// `responder` is referencing your view controller A. You will have to cast it.
```

Comment: Cheers guys. The way I have done it is to override the initWithNibName so that it has a delegate perimeter. then pass through self from the MainViewController. Don't know if this is the best way to do It though. Basically Im making a pointer to the delegate class. ` -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil delegate:(id<addViewDelegate>)d
{
    if (self == [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]){
    //if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.delegate = d;
    }
    
    return self;
}
`

Comment: `-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil delegate:(id<addViewDelegate>)d
`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this especially if it is a static method:

**ViewControllerB**

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

- (void)dismissView{
    //implementation to close the view

    [ViewControllerA methodName:perimeter];
}
```

Good Luck!